# create inflated map

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS Users
is it possible to create an inflated map from a static map? It would be useful to know if a measurement of a laser sensor come from object in the map or not
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199347/create-inflated-map/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-12-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK no tool to edit map files for your specific purpose is provided by ROS. You can edit maps manually. See [1](http://answers.ros.org/question/11641/manually-editing-maps/), [2](http://answers.ros.org/question/12217/effects-of-manually-editing-gmapping-maps/) for example.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0